# Python 3 - Read & Write from & to .csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read data from a CSV file (A), extract data, and write that to a different CSV file (B). In the new file B, I want to have two rows. The first row should contain all the predefined variables and row 2 should be filled with all the values that belong to the specific variable in row 1.

**(A) Python code**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(str)

#Make a list with the predefined variables
definition = ["record_id", "abbreviation", "patient_id", "study_id",
"step_count", "distance", "ambulation_time", "velocity", "cadence",
"normalized_velocity", "step_time_differential", "step_length_differential",
"cycle_time_differential", "step_time", "step_length", "step_extremity",
"cycle_time", "stride_length", "hh_base_support", "swing_time",
"stance_time", "single_supp_time", "double_supp_time", "toe_in_out"]

#Read the GaitRite .csv
with open('C:/Users/Kay_v/Documents/School/Exports/Export 3.csv', 'r')  as f, open('C:/Users/Kay_v/Documents/School/Exports/result.csv', 'w') as outfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=definition, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()

#Read the .csv row by row
    for row in reader:
        #print(row)
        for item in definition:
            h = item.replace('_', '')
            r0 = row[0].lower().replace(' ', '')
            if h in r0:
                try:
                    avg = round((float(row[1].replace(',', '.')) + float(row[2].replace(',', '.'))) / 2, 2)
            except ValueError:
                avg = 0  # for cases with entry strings or commas
                #print(avg)
                print(h, r0, row[1], row[2])
                data[item] = row[1]

    data['record_id'] = 1

# Write the clean result.csv
    writer.writerow(data)
```

**(B) Desired output**

```
record_id  abbreviation  study_id  step_count  distance 
1                                  3           292,34
```

With the help of "Moses Koledoye" i managed to read and write most of the variables into a clean .csv file. The problem i am experiencing is the following:

**Problem (1)**

In the result.csv(the clean .csv output file) i am missing the values of the following variables:

```
step_time
step_length
cycle_time  
stride_length   
hh_base_support 
swing_time  
stance_time 
single_supp_time    
double_supp_time    
toe_in_out
```

I used this part of the code to check the outcomes:

```
print(h, r0, row[1], row[2])
```

which gives me back the following info:

```
stepcount stepcount 3  
distance distance 292,34  
ambulationtime ambulationtime 1,67  
velocity velocity 175,1  
cadence cadence 107,8  
velocity normalizedvelocity ,  
normalizedvelocity normalizedvelocity ,  
steptimedifferential steptimedifferential 0,004  
steptime steptimedifferential 0,004  
steplengthdifferential steplengthdifferential 1,051  
steplength steplengthdifferential 1,051  
cycletimedifferential cycletimedifferential 0,008  
cycletime cycletimedifferential 0,008  
steptime steptime(sec) 0,558 0,554
steplength steplength(cm) 96,746 97,797
stepextremity stepextremity(ratio) , ,
cycletime cycletime(sec) 1,116 1,108
stridelength stridelength(cm) 192,159 197,122
hhbasesupport hhbasesupport(cm) 2,988 6,32
swingtime swingtime(sec) 0,466 0,466
stancetime stancetime(sec) 0,65 0,642
velocity stridevelocity 172,185 177,908
steptime steptimestddev , 0,006
stridelength stridelengthstddev , ,
swingtime swingtimestddev , ,
stancetime stancetimestddev , ,
velocity stridevelocitystddev , ,
singlesupptime singlesupptimestddev , ,
doublesupptime doublesupptimestddev , ,
```

From the above output, you can see there are some problems with names matching with multiple strings(like velocity) and some not matching at all(like toe_in_out)

**Problem (2)**

The other problem is about including the averages into the result.csv.
I am using this part of the code to calculate the average, whenever a variable has two values. But i would like this average to also be included in the output result.csv.

```
try:
    avg = round((float(row[1].replace(',', '.')) + float(row[2].replace(',', '.'))) / 2, 2)
except ValueError:
    avg = 0  # for cases with entry strings or commas
```

I hope anyone can help me with these problems, would be highly appreciated!

If you like, you can play with the export file you can download it here:
[CSV export file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03062446993293567917)